# How do I merge a branch into a subfolder of my master branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, repository, subdirectory

I am inexperienced with git and use Github to host my website. I just finished an updated "new" branch. I want to merge New into a subfolder in Master so that I can share the link and get feedback before before I replace my current website.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. To merge like that your branch will have to have the same structure as master, you can't merge a branch directly into a folder.

Comment: Yes, it seems you're confusing some definitions here. Merges are made between whole branches, you don't target any specific folder or subfolder in the process. If you want to somehow backup your current version before replacing it with the upgraded version, this IS what git does. Each commit IS a backup. But It's more than likely that I misunderstood your situation. Maybe elaborate a bit on your context?

Answer (score 1):

[Github pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) (PR) are generally used for review purposes.

After committing and pushing the changes to the new branch, create a PR in Github from the new branch to merge the changes to master.

The person who is looking at the pull request can review the changes and provide the feedback on the PR.